# Leaflet Baselayer behavior

Tags: javascript, leaflet, theory

Does Leaflet draw all Baselayer during initalizing in the order of the the listing in the layer control?
And if so, can this behavior be changed?

I'm have a map with 3 baselayer which are SVG and have transparent parts in them. So far everything  is fine. But the odd thing is that when I first load the map it draws all 3 layers at once in the opposite order than they are listed in the layer control (botton one in listing is top one drawn).
As soon as I click any of the baseLayer in the control, the other 2 disappear and the application works as expected.

```
var map = L.map('map', {crs: L.CRS.Simple, layers: [pneumaticSensor, 
laserSensor, touchSensor, powerMeters], minZoom: -1});
var bounds = [[0,0],[700,1000]];
map.fitBounds(bounds);

var overlayBounds = [[0,-60],[712,1000]];
//ImageOverlays
var toolBounds = [[-300,-4.5], [800,1000]];
var toolUrl = 'source/images/WerkzeugLayer.svg';
tools = L.imageOverlay(toolUrl, toolBounds).addTo(map);
var rubberbandUrl = 'source/images/gummiband.svg';
rubberband = L.imageOverlay(rubberbandUrl, overlayBounds).addTo(map);

var productionLineUrl = 'source/images/laufbaender.svg';
productionline = L.imageOverlay(productionLineUrl, overlayBounds).addTo(map);

var othersUrl = 'source/images/sonstiges.svg';
others = L.imageOverlay(othersUrl, overlayBounds).addTo(map);

var overlays = {
    '<img class="bubbles" src="source/images/legendeGruen.svg" /> 
Pneumatikzylinder' : pneumaticSensor,
    '<img class="bubbles" src="source/images/legendeBlau.svg" /> 
Laufbandsensoren' : laserSensor,
    '<img class="bubbles" src="source/images/legendeGelb.svg" /> 
Drucksensoren' : touchSensor,
    '<img class="bubbles" src="source/images/legendeGrau.svg" /> 
Leistungsmesser' : powerMeters,
    'Werkzeug' : tools
};

var baseLayers = {
'Gummibänder' : rubberband,
'Förderband' : productionline }

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: In the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) they say that "when using multiple base layers, only one of them should be added to the map at instantiation, but all of them should be present in the base layers object when creating the layers control". Can you share how you're initializing the map?

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson added it to the question

Comment: Having seen the code, I'll emphasize what @Chase quoted: "only one of them should be added to the map at instantiation". You're adding more tan one.